# what's the meaning of ^@ in syslog

Tags: linux, debian, shutdown, syslog

One physical machine had shutdown unexpected, there is no any error log about that, only get a large `^@` in one line of `/var/log/syslog` file such as:

```
Dec  9 21:50:02 hostname CRON[74324]: (root) MAIL (mailed 716 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MAT#012)
^@^@^@...large of ^@^@^@Dec 10 09:51:49 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Dec 10 09:51:49 hostname kernel: [...
```

Machine shutdowned at `Dec 9 21:50` unexpected, and start by manual at `Dec 10 09:51:49`.

How could I find the root cause of it shutdown unexpected?

Where did it `Flush Journal to`?

What's the meaning of `^@` in syslog, and how could I read it?

Comment: Possible partial duplicate of [System crash - strange chars in syslog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477537/system-crash-strange-chars-in-syslog) or of [What does ^@^@^@ mean in a text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/108321)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are NUL bytes (i.e. bytes with a numerical value of zero), those should not exist in text files.

The crash caused the file to be extended without the data being written.

Comment: How could I find the couse of crash?

Comment: As the question about what `^@` means is answered in several other similar questions, anwers to this question should probably focus on the other parts of the question.